# Why aren't some the daily brachot made only once in a lifetime?

Tags: blessing, gentiles, women

some of the daily blessings such as thanking God for not making me a non-Jew or (in my case) a woman seem to be things which one would only make a blessing for once in a lifetime. Why are they made daily instead?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between that set of blessings and the other morning blessings, like for sight or clothing. You also only start seeing once per life.

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, I think not-Alex is only providing examples. However, for clothing it would indeed apply (as that is a continuos type of thing). Even for eyesight, one can argue for keeping it healthy.

Comment: @yydl I'm not sure what you mean. These aren't prayers for the future.

Comment: @doubleAA True. But they are acknowledgement about what is done for us on a continual basis.

Answer (score 4):

In general the morning blessings are a form of Birchas Hanehnin, which we would say every time we benefit, not once in a lifetime.

Shulchan Aruch HaRav [writes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/46/1.htm):

> ברכות השחר תקנום חכמים על סדר העולם והנהגתו מה שהבריות נהנין בכל יום שיברכו להקדוש ברוך הוא על זה בפעם ראשונה שנהנין הנאה זו בכל יום ויום להשלים מנין המאה ברכותה שחייב כל אדם לברך בכל יום ויום
>
> The morning blessings were extablished by the Sages according to the order of the world and its patterns, that which creations enjoy every day, that they should bless G-d on this the first time they benifit from this benifit every single day, in order to complete the number of 100 blessings that a person is required to say every single day.

(See [here](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/46/7.htm) for why it isn't necessarily required to actually experience the matter that we are saying a blessing on, like hearing a rooster.)

Regarding those blessings specifically - besides the general fact that the requirement is to say it every day anew even though the experience didn't stop other than by sleeping - [he writes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/46/4.htm):

> ולפי דברי המקובלים שברכות אלו הן על יציאת נשמתו בלילה שלא נדבק בה נשמת גוי או עבד או אשה גם הגר יכול לברך כן
>
> And according to the words of the Kabbalists that these blessings are on the departure of his soul at night, that the soul of a Goy, Eved or Isha did not connect to him, also a convert is able to bless this way (שלא עשני גוי).

(The Magen Avraham is the source of this as halacha).

So there is an aspect to these blessings which are not about how a person was initially born. Besides this, since these blessings are about [Mitzvos that a person](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/46/5) is obligated in and בכל יום יהיו בעיניך כחדשים, a person should feel that the Mitzvos are something received new every single day.

Answer (score 3):

The arizal answers that each night a person returns his soul to the creator and it possible that this soul be switched into another body or state of being. Therefore each day that a person awakes to find himself in this particular configuration of body and soul he must make a blessing anew.

Comment: Where does the Ari say this?

Comment: @DoubleAA eitz chayim, heichal adam kadmon, shaar alef, anaf heh. CF Likutei Halachos (R' Nathan Sternhartz) Yoreh Deah, Basar B'Chalav 4:1

Comment: This is also kind of an answer to trans-gender people min hatorah minayin....

Comment: @not-allowed to change my name, I've just read these sources and I don't see how they can serve as a source to this answer. Can you reference specific lines?

Answer (score 0):

Because each day you have the ability to perform new Mitzvot (obligations) based on these factors. Although the fact of your genealogy or gender doesn't change, it is a brand new day with new opportunities.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, General, and thanks for your contribution. I hope you enjoy the site and stick around. Sources are prized on this site; while your answer is a good one even if it's your own reasoning, it's even better if you can [edit] in a source for the argument you put forth.

Answer (score 0):

I heard from Rav Gudlevsky (http://azamra.co.il), that every day and even every moment Creation is made anew.

So person should be happy every moment, that he/she still has all the blessings. Even such seemingly constant things as being a jew or being male or female can be taken away, G-d forbid.

There are plenty examples, that people not sure about who they are.

Answer (score 0):

the point is to get in the habit of being thankful. a one time event won't change a person so much as the Rambam writes regarding charity

“If a person gives 1,000 coins at one time and to one person, this is inferior to the one who gives 1,000 times with 1,000 coins … for the latter case multiplies the spirit of generosity 1,000 times over, while giving just once will arouse awaken the spirit of generosity once, and then it ends.” – Commentary to Mishna Avot 3:15

Comment: A source that the reason we recite those blessings daily is to accustom ourselves to thank would be most valuable.

Comment: http://www.aish.com/sp/48w/48971986.html - Rabbi Noach Weinberg zt'l:  To really get into gear, you need to find your rhythm....That's why Judaism has certain pre-set activities every day. When waking up, for example, we say: "Thank God I'm alive." It's a moment of conscious appreciation for getting another chance, another day. This awareness gets us up on the right side of the bed, starting our day on a high note.

Comment: I meant [edit]ed in to your answer.