# Reincarnations - Let's work out how many one would need to be personally obligated in all 613 Mitzvot in the superset

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah

In a nutshell, the Arizal says (Shaar Gilgulim Ch. 16) we are reincarnated in order that every Jew gets a chance to experience all 613 mitzvot as a *chiyuv* (personal obligation) at least once. **My question is, how many reincarnations would that take, minimum, and which category of Jew would each of those incarnations be?** Show your work :)

###### The framing of "reincarnations" is not the point, I am actually just interested in the theory of minimum Jewish categories required to be *mechuyav* in all the Mitzvot

E.g. we would need both a Yisrael and a Cohen reincarnation. What else? Can it really be 4 people (Asarah Perakim L'Ramchal 10:3)? If not, what's the minimum? Clever/efficient combinations should be utilised, of course.

Note:

- Entire life is taken into account, so no need for separate *gilgulim* (reincarnations) for parents and children etc.
- People required to assist the hypothetical *gilgul* are not included in the count. This is not practical - it is theoretical, therefore
- Leave *matzav* (practical circumstance) out of this. Doesn't matter if some mitzvot have never actually been *l'maaseh* (practically available to abstain/perform), all we care about is if the *gilgul* is theoretically *mechuyav*, and leave the practicals, such as Temple standing, etc. to Hashem

Comment: In the same vein, the Mishna in Makkot 21b tells us how one could break 8 commandments with a simple gesture.

Comment: This should be a movie! (Well it's actually closer to reality) A little off track of your question, but in this scenario The Mitzvah Dream Team have to help other actual Gilguilim to fulfill all the Mitzvos for Moshiach to come, but the Yetzer Harah is hell-bent on stopping the mitzvah dream team.